# In C# can we ever use protected access modifier for an interface?

Tags: c#

The default access modifier for an interface is public. However, 
in C# can we ever use protected access modifier for an interface?

Comment: Do you mean the members of the interface, or the interface itself? _Edited_ All declared members of an interface are always public. The accessibility of the interface itself can be `protected` if the interface is nested inside a non-static, non-sealed outer `class`.

Comment: as far as I remember, you can't specify a access modifier for the interface members.

Comment: look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516148/why-cant-i-have-protected-interface-members

Comment: Sure, you can declare a nested interface protected.  Why you'd ever do something like this is hard to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this acceccibility.

See this page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx.

It's say that "Interfaces declared directly within a namespace can be declared as public or internal and, just like classes and structs, interfaces default to internal access."

Be carefull, as you see in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx members are public by default and can't be modified.

Comment: That page talks about accessibility of *members*, not the interface itself.

Comment: This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) talks about interfaces and their members.

Answer (score 4):

In this example:

```
class C
{
  protected interface I
  {
  }
}
```

the nested type `I` is `protected`.

This means that `I` is visible to all of `C` and also to all classes that derive from `C`. For example this could be used to make `protected` instance methods inside `C` that contain `I` in their signatures or return types.

**Note:** The default accessibility for an interface is not `public`, like you claim. The default accessibility for a *member* of an interface is `public`. That is something else.

The default accessibility for the interface itself depends on what the interface itself is a member of. If the interface is a member of an "outer" `class` or `struct` (like my `C` above), it has the usual default accessibility of `class` and `struct` members, which is `private`. If the interface is a direct member of a `namespace` (possibly the global namespace), the default accessibility is the usual default for all non-nested types, which is `internal`.