# Base class implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop

1. What are the cons/risks of base class implementing an interface?
2. Is it better to always implement an interface on the sub-class?
3. When would you use one or the other?

   ```
   public interface IFriendly
   {
       string GetFriendly();
   }


   public abstract class Person: IFriendly
   {
       public abstract string GetFriendly(); 
   }
   ```

   VS.

   ```
   public interface IFriendly
   {
       string GetFriendly();
   }

   public abstract class Person
   {
      // some other stuff i would like subclasses to have
   }

   public abstract class Employee : Person, IFriendly
   {
       public string GetFriendly()
       {
           return "friendly";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Implement in the base class when ***ALL*** derived classes will use this implementation; otherwise leave abstract.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you need to think of it that way:

```
public interface IBreathing
{
    void Breathe();
}

//because every human breathe
public abstract class Human : IBreathing
{
    abstract void Breathe();
}

public interface IVillain
{
    void FightHumanity();
}

public interface IHero
{
    void SaveHumanity();
}

//not every human is a villain
public class HumanVillain : Human, IVillain
{
    void Breathe() {}
    void FightHumanity() {}
}

//but not every is a hero either
public class HumanHero : Human, IHero
{
    void Breathe() {}
    void SaveHumanity() {}
}
```

The point is that you base class should implement interface (or inherit but only expose its definition as abstract) only if every other class that derives from it should also implement that interface.
So, with basic example provided above, you'd make `Human` implement `IBreathing` only if every `Human` breaths (which is correct here).

But! You can't make `Human` implement both `IVillain` and `IHero` because that would make us unable to distinguish later on if it's one or another. Actually, such implementation would imply that every `Human` is both a villain and hero at once.

**To wrap up answers to your question:**

1. **What are the cons/risks of base class implementing an interface?**

   None, if every class deriving from it should implement that interface too.
2. **Is it better to always implement an interface on the sub-class?**

   If every class deriving from base one should also implement that interface, it's rather a **must**
3. **When would you use one or the other?**

   If every class deriving from base one should implement such interface, make base class inherit it. If not, make concrete class implement such interface.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a base class ties you to the implementation of the base class. We always start off thinking the base class is exactly what we want. Then we need a new inherited class and it doesn't quite fit, so we find ourselves going back and modifying the base class to fit the needs of the inherited class. It happens all the time.

If you start with an interface then you have a little more flexibility. Instead of having to modify the base class you can just write a new class that implements the interface. You can have the benefit of class inheritance when it works, but you're not tied to it when it doesn't work.

I loved class inheritance when I first started with OOP. What's surprising is how infrequently it ends up being practical. That's where the principal of [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) comes in. It's preferable to build functionality out of combinations of classes rather than having it nested inside inherited classes.

There's also the [Open/Closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) principle. If you can inherit, great, but you don't want to have to go back and change the base class (and risk breaking other stuff) because it's needed for a new inherited class to work right. Programming to an interface instead of a base class can protect you from having to modify existing base classes.