# Cannot implement property with protected set from interface

Tags: c#, interface, c#-8.0

I have an interface which has a property with public get and protected set.

Yet when I implement this in my class i get an error saying it must be public.

My interface looks like this:

```
public interface ISegment
{
    INode NodeA { get; protected set; }
    INode NodeB { get; protected set; }
    public sealed void SetNodeA(INode node) => NodeA = node;
    public sealed void SetNodeB(INode node) => NodeB = node;
}
```

My class `Segment : ISegment` has the properties declared like this:

```
[SerializeField]
protected Node _nodeA;
public INode NodeA
{
    get => _nodeA;
    protected set => _nodeA = value as Node;
}

[SerializeField]
protected Node _nodeB;
public INode NodeB
{
    get => _nodeB;
    protected set => _nodeB = value as Node;
}
```

And i get this error:

```
'Segment' does not implement interface member 'ISegment.NodeA.set'
'Segment' does not implement interface member 'ISegment.NodeB.set'
```

What am i misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
    public interface ISegment
    {
        INode NodeA { get; protected set; }
        INode NodeB { get; protected set; }
        public sealed void SetNodeA(INode node) => NodeA = node;
        public sealed void SetNodeB(INode node) => NodeB = node;
    }

    public class MyClass : ISegment
    {
        private Node _nodeA;
        private Node _nodeB;

        INode ISegment.NodeA
        {
            get => _nodeA;
            set => _nodeA = value as Node;
        }

        INode ISegment.NodeB
        {
            get => _nodeB;
            set => _nodeB = value as Node;
        }

        private void Do(INode node)
        {
            if(node == NodeA) { } // Error
            if(node == _nodeA) { } // Warning "Possibly unintended reference comparison"
            if (node == ((ISegment)this).NodeA) { } // OK
        }
    }
```

but the Question is, why do you want that? Why `protected set`?

You can do it like this also. (Not helps here because of default implementation in the interface)

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
        public string Bar { get; }
    }

    public class Bubu : IFoo
    {
        public string Bar { get; protected set; }
    }
```

**Update:** Edited the code to show more exactly, how to access the properties

Comment: Not sure i see a difference here? Your property isn't even declared public in the class? As for why, because i only want derived classes to access it, everything else has to use the method.

Comment: This is explicit interface property implementation. You can access the getter like normal public property but not the setter

Comment: I'm confused how your first code example is any different to mine other than not declaring the setter modifier which makes it look private in your case which isn't what i wanted.

Comment: AFAIK you can't access protected interface members within a implementing class.

Comment: Ah so it has to be public ? Damn thats annoying. Seems like a new access modifier is needed for this grey zone.

Comment: I added some example to show how it works. You have to cast to `IFoo` to be able to access the property in the first example

Comment: Or maybe you could create an abstract base class that provides the protected setter.

Comment: @DemetriusAxenowski Are you sure that the protected setter can be accessed in this way?

Comment: @DemetriusAxenowski why would you need to cast if you already derive from the interface?

Comment: protected setter makes only sense, if you want to inherit from that class. So yes, in derived classes

Comment: @DemetriusAxenowski yeah but it already is derived, i said `Segment : ISegment` so the cast is unusual to me.

Comment: @WDUK I don't want it, I have to. Thats because of the `protected set`. You can not implement it in "normal" way. You have to do it like my example shows

Comment: Also it didn't work for me i get a new error `Modifier public is not valid for this item`

Comment: Once again, why declare the setter as protected in the interface? Here is a question about protected and interfaces https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516148/why-cant-i-have-protected-interface-members

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244102/discussion-between-demetrius-axenowski-and-wduk).

Comment: The setter is there because the interface has default implementation. So i don't need to declare the `public` aspect of the property because the cast does it for me? Thats kind've weird.